# Store ids in C Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I would like to create a C array, which stores some objects but would like to declare it as follows:

```
id array = malloc(sizeof(NSObject * 4));
```

But this gives an error; it asks me to either:

> Fix it - use __bridge to convert directly (No change in ownership).

Or:

> Fixe it: use CFBridgeRelease to call to transfer ownership of a +1
>   'void' into ARC.

I have tried both, but it still gives an error:

> Missing )

I remember having done this; but I forgot how since it has been a while.

How can I store `id`s in C array and retrieve things out of it and then cast them down?

Comment: What type is `id`? `void*`, `NSObject*` or something else?

Comment: `id` is just Objective-C `id`.

Comment: @Deduplicator `id` is defined as a pointer to any ObjC Object.

Comment: What's wrong with Xcode's fix suggestion?    `id thing = (__bridge id)(malloc(sizeof(NSObject*)));`

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian The error is as written above "Missing )". Question: `id` is pointer to struct that points to any Objective-C, so when I declare the C array, would I need to "deference" it to allocate the correct amount? Because all pointers are of the same size?

Comment: are you sure that brackets are placed correctly? should be `id array = malloc(sizeof(NSObject) * 4);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of a pointer is the same for all types, including objects, so the following is all you need:

```
id *myArray = malloc(sizeof(void *) * 4);
```

Note that the type used on the left in the posted example was also incorrect, since the memory being allocated is expected to be referenced as a C array of pointers to objects, rather than just an object.

If you're compiling with ARC enabled, you'll need to add a lifetime qualifier to the declaration of `myArray`, and cast the return value of `malloc`. That's because ARC can only manage the lifetimes of pointers to objects and the array in which you're going to store the objects is a C type. For example, to tell ARC explicitly that the pointers in the array are unmanaged you could modify the previous code as follows:

```
    __unsafe_unretained id *myArray = (__unsafe_unretained id *) malloc(sizeof(void *) * 4);
```

Note that since ARC can't manage retain counts in C arrays, it will be up to you to ensure that whatever you store in the array can be used safely.

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting this error using the solution above: _implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer type 'void*' to `__strong id *' is disallowed with ARC_.

Comment: This seems to be working. But I am very curious about this: is it true that we should never cast the return value of `malloc` for good practice-sake and could you please tell me if this would violate good practice - `(__unsafe_unretained id *)`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now I remember what I wanted to ask as well: with the solution above, does that mean that `void *` is the same as `id *`? But I thought `id` itself is already a pointer. So would `id*` mean it is declared as a pointer to a pointer to `id`?

Comment: `void *` means a pointer to something of unspecified type, whereas `id` means pointer to an object. `id *` means pointer to a pointer of type `id`. `id` is a typedef for `struct objc_object *`, so the typedef includes the `*`.

Comment: @Unheilig You asked, "is it true that we should never cast the return value of malloc for good practice-sake." Where did you hear that? In some cases a cast would be unnecessary and thus would simply add meaningless clutter to the code, but in this case it's needed in order to provide the ARC compiler with sufficient type information to make compiling the code possible.

Answer (score -1):

You can't store arrays of objects in Objective-C. It only allow allocating pointers to objects. To do that, the right syntax would be like this:

```
id *array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * 4);
```

or possibly

```
id *array = malloc(sizeof(id) * 4);
```

but the former is more DRY.

Comment: Thanks, but both version give an error: _pointer to non-const type 'id' with no explicit ownership_.